# Spark - Can a MultiMap be converted to a DataFrame in JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark, guava, multimap

I'm trying to convert a MultiMap of billions of data values to a Spark DataFrame to run calculations on then write the results to a cassandra table.

I generate the multimap from the following cassandra query and loop.  I'd be happy to take suggestions if there would be a better way to get and manipulate this data into a DataFrame like I am with the loop.

**Code Updated With Answer:**

```
//Build ResultSet from cassandra query for data manipulation.
        Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT \"Power\",\"Bandwidth\",\"Start_Frequency\" FROM \"SB1000_49552019\".\"Measured_Value\";");
        //Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT power, bandwidth, start_frequency FROM model.reports;");
        stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
        ResultSet results = session.execute(stmt);

// Get the Variables from each Row of Cassandra Data        
 Multimap<Double, Float> data = LinkedListMultimap.create();
        for (Row row : results){       
           // Column Names in Cassandra (Case Sensitive)
           start_frequency = row.getDouble("Start_Frequency");
           power = row.getFloat("Power");
           bandwidth = row.getDouble("Bandwidth"); 

// Create Channel Power Buckets, place information into prepared statement binding, write to cassandra.            
                for(channel = 1.6000E8; channel <= channel_end;  ){ 
                    if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) {     
                     data.put(channel, power);
                    }  // end if
                    channel+=increment;
                }  // end for      
        } // end "row" for

// Create Spark List for DataFrame        
        List<Value> values = data.asMap().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(y -> new Value(x.getKey(), y)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Create DataFrame and Calculate Results
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(values), Value.class).groupBy(col("channel"))
        .agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
        .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)      
        .option("table", "results")
        .option("keyspace", "model")
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();

    } // end session
} // End Compute 

public class Value implements Serializable {
    public Value(Double channel, Float power) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.power = power;
    }
    Double channel;
    Float power;

    public void setChannel(Double channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
    public void setPower(Float power) {
        this.power = power;
    }
    public Double getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }
    public Float getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +channel +","+power+"]";
    }
}
```

The sample multimap has the types {Double}=[Float] where there may be multiple Float items for each Double

**EXAMPLE**

```
{1.50E8=[10, 20], 1.51E8=[-10, -13, -14, -15], 1.52E8=[-10, -11]
```

I need to use spark to get the min, max, average of each of these.  For example for the first one 1.50ED would be min 10, max 20, avg 15.

I already have the code that I can use once I can get it in a temptable and operated on as a dataframe:

```
queryMV.groupBy(col("channel"))
.agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
.write().mode(SaveMode.Append)      
.option("table", "results")
.option("keyspace", "model")
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();
```

I would be grateful for some tips on how to convert the multimap into a DataFrame using JAVA.  I haven't been able to find any documenation about using multimaps with spark.

Im currently using a solution that does the initial query and with the for loop writes the raw data to a new table that I can in turn directly map to a temptable / dataframe but that takes to much time since I have to write billions of rows to cassandra before calculating.  I'd like to use a multimap or something similar and convert directly to spark for calculation.

Comment: I want to use spark because this calculation would be handled on over a billion different values.  The Table would be  like the following:   'key: value, value, value '  I need to take the key and get the min, max and avg of the values.  For example if my key is 1.50E8 and my values are 10, 20  my output should be 1.50E8  Min 10, Max 20, Avg 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas the Java `parallelize` method takes either a list of `T` or for `parallelizePairs` a list of `Tuple<K, V>`. So you will need to convert. While the `createDataFrame` only works of RDDs and Scala `Seq` and needs a schema (either a bean or a StructType).

To make it Even More Fun `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableEntry` is not serializable, so you need to convert in Java, so a Java-ficated version of @Pankaj Arora solution would not work unless you moved the conversion logic into Java. I.e.

```
public class Value implements Serializable {
    public Value(Double a, Float b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    Double a;
    Float b;

    public void setA(Double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void setB(Float b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public Double getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public Float getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[" +a +","+b+"]";
    }
}


    Multimap<Double, Float> data = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    data.put(1d, 1f);
    data.put(1d, 2f);
    data.put(2d, 3f);

    List<Value> values = data.asMap().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(y -> new Value(x.getKey(), y)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(values), Value.class).show();
```

Given your edit I'd look at creating objects (rather than a multimap) from the off.

Comment: could you provide an example of that loop please?

Comment: Done. But do you ever use that multimap? I'd suggest you skip that step and create (better named) `Value` objects directly in the loading step.

Comment: I was only using the multimap because I wasn't sure on how else to compile all of the data correctly prior to sending it to the dataframe.  If you know of a better way I'd love the advice since this is operating on billions of objects efficiencly is critical.  By the way your solution for my multimap version works perfectly.

Comment: If the data size Is large probably you will not be able to load it using parallelize. Because whole data has to be loaded into driver memory and also if driver has enough memory it will be too slow. Are you reading data from hdfs ?

Comment: If it is a large data set then maybe looking for a spark cassandra connector is the way to go.

Comment: I am currently using the spark cassandra connector. I could connect directly to the raw data but wasn't sure how to put it in buckets like i was doing with the multimap before running the spark calculation.  The dataset right now is currently around a billion cassandra rows with values that need to be crunched.

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Output(a : Double ,b : Int )
val input = Map(1.50E8-> List(10, 20) ,  1.51E8-> List( -10, -13, -14, -15 ), 1.52E8-> List(-10, -11)).toArray
val inputRdd = sc.parallelize(input)
val queryMV = inputRdd.flatMap(x=> x._2.map(y=> Output(x._1, y))).toDF
```

Comment: This looks very promising.  One thing I would need to do though is use the   Map without knowing what the values are ahead of time. This appears to be SCALA is it the same in JAVA except without the val prefix?