# How to Replace JAVA loop with Direct Spark Cassandra Table Data Manipulation

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I"m trying to make my code more efficient since i have to process billions of rows of data in cassandra.  I currently use a JAVA loop within the Datastax Cassandra Spark Connector to pull out the data and put it into a format that I'm familiar with [(multimap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508003/spark-can-a-multimap-be-converted-to-a-dataframe-in-java) in order to get spark to do the manipulation.  I'd like to be able to replace this Multimap loop with a direct spark manipulation of the cassandra table to save time and make everything more efficient. I'd greatly appreciate any code suggestions to accomplish that. Here is my existing code:

```
        Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT \"Power\",\"Bandwidth\",\"Start_Frequency\" FROM \"SB1000_49552019\".\"Measured_Value\";");
        stmt.setFetchSize(2000000);
        ResultSet results = session.execute(stmt);

// Get the Variables from each Row of Cassandra Data        
        Multimap<Double, Float> data = LinkedListMultimap.create();
        for (Row row : results){       
           // Column Names in Cassandra (Case Sensitive)
           start_frequency = row.getDouble("Start_Frequency");
           power = row.getFloat("Power");
           bandwidth = row.getDouble("Bandwidth"); 

// Create Channel Power Buckets    
                for(channel = 1.6000E8; channel <= channel_end;  ){ 
                    if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) {     
                     data.put(channel, power);
                    }  // end if
                    channel+=increment;
                }  // end for      
        } // end "row" for

// Create Spark List for DataFrame        
        List<Value> values = data.asMap().entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(y -> new Value(x.getKey(), y)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Create DataFrame and Calculate Results
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(values), Value.class).groupBy(col("channel"))
        .agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
        .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)      
        .option("table", "results")
        .option("keyspace", "model")
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();

    } // end session
} // End Compute
```

Comment: Check out this example https://github.com/rssvihla/datastax_work/blob/master/spark_commons/examples/spark_bulk_operations/src/main/scala/pro/foundev/scala/BulkUpgrade.scala

Comment: I"m sorry I dont see how that is similar??

Comment: The point is, you shouldn't be reading with the java driver directly and then processing with spark. Use the spark context cassandraTable method and let spark do the reads for you in a parallel, partitioned, node local fashion.

Comment: I understand using spark cassandratable but my issue is not knowing how to use spark to change the data the way I am in the Java for loop. That's what I need help with.  I want to get rid of the Java loop that's the whole point of the post.

Comment: The channel filtering could happen in a .filter or even in a .where if your table is partitioned to handle that query. Then you can apply the groupby, ideally it would be a spanby instead for performance.

Comment: Channel isn't in the original raw data it is generated by the for loop.  How would that be accomplished with spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JavaRDD<MeasuredValue> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("SB1000_47130646", "Measured_Value", mapRowTo(MeasuredValue.class));
JavaRDD<Value> valueRdd = rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<MeasuredValue, Value>(){
@Override 
public Iterable<Value> call(MeasuredValue row) throws Exception { 
double start_frequency = row.getStart_frequency(); 
float power = row.getPower(); 
double bandwidth = row.getBandwidth(); 

// Define Variable 
double channel,channel_end, increment;  

// Initialize Variables 
channel_end = 1.6159E8; 
increment = 5000; 

List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(); 
// Create Channel Power Buckets 
for(channel = 1.6000E8; channel <= channel_end; ){ 
if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) { 
list.add(new Value(channel, power)); 
} // end if 
channel+=increment; 
} // end for 

return list; 
}    
    });

    sqlContext.createDataFrame(valueRdd, Value.class).groupBy(col("channel"))
    .agg(min("power"), max("power"), avg("power"))
    .write().mode(SaveMode.Append)      
    .option("table", "results")
    .option("keyspace", "model")
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").save();

} // end session

public static class MeasuredValue implements Serializable {

        public MeasuredValue() { }

        private double start_frequency;
        public double getStart_frequency() { return start_frequency; }
        public void setStart_frequency(double start_frequency) { this.start_frequency = start_frequency; }

        private double bandwidth ;
        public double getBandwidth() { return bandwidth; }
        public void setBandwidth(double bandwidth) { this.bandwidth = bandwidth; }

        private float power;    
        public float getPower() { return power; }
        public void setPower(float power) { this.power = power; }

    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to establish the schema in the MeasuredValue class with getters and setters?  Also the `rdd.flatMap(row ->`   lambda causes errors saying required `FlatMapFunction<MeasuredValue,U>` `but found (row)->{ d[...];}}` and in the for channel loop it is complaining that `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`  I think i would also need to do a `mapRowTo` within the initial `JavaRDD` statement wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes those things needed to be done. The code that i wrote is just for reference it needs some modifications.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt like using a row lambda on a JavaRDD

Comment: I have changed the solution to not use lambda expressions. Can you check now.

Comment: Ok, I made the changes.  Now I get:  `The type of <U>flatMap(FlatMapFunction<T,U>) is erroneous where U,T are type-variables:   U extends Object decalred in method <U>flatMapt(FlatMapFunction<T,U>) T extends Object declared in class AbstreactJavaRDDLike      incompatible types:inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s) inferred: Spark_Reports.Value equality contraints(s): Spark_Reprots.Value,String `  and I also get  `missing return statement`

Comment: Can you continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104311/discussion-between-mithrix-and-pankaj-arora).